# How to get Item's ExtraFields to display in latest.php of K2 - Joomla

Tags: joomla-2.5, k2

Im trying to get ExtraFields from K2 Articles. I have assigned my menu to `Latest from Users or Categories` in order to display all articles from several categories.

It displays fine. But these articles have ExtraFields information that I want to display, but there is no option to display ExtraFields, so I suppose that in order to do this I need to change `latest.php` page, which is the page used to display all articles from different Categories.

As `latest.php` doesn't display ExtraFields I'm trying to code it as the following:

```
<?php  
$extrafields = array();
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $item)
{    
$extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}   
?>    
<?php if(isset($extrafields[X]) === true):?>
<?php echo $extrafields[X]; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Though, I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

I've been searching ways to get ExtraFields, found some solutions but this is the error i get every time.

Any ideas or solutions?

Best regards.

I'm using joomla 2.5.

Comment: First: Migrate to Joomla 3.x
Second: Get more familiar with PHP. `$item->extra_fields` seems to be something different than an  array. If you need a better answer, you should provide more details. Which 'lastest.php'? Which `ExtraFields`?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I don't want to migrate to Joomla 3.x. I want to stay in 2.5 (I know that I should, but not for this website). I provided more details in my question. Can you figure out what I want?

Comment: You should ensure that `$this->item` contains extra fields. Please do a `var_dump($this->item);` and check for extra fields there.

Comment: This may not help, but the one time I worked on some K2 stuff, only the item page used $this->item, anything that wasn't the actual item page used $item->. I'm not a programmer though, so it's possible the for each statement will get around that, but I just know in a module we wanted to pull extra fields into did NOT work using $this.

Comment: Do you know which template you have to modify, and how to make the matching template override? `latest.php` is part of `com_k2`, and (at least in the J3.5-version) has a subtemplate called `latest_item.php`. Create a template override of this one and edit. (and for the template override don't miss to copy the whole folder `com_k2/templates` since the overriding only works with the files lying in that folder.)

Comment: Did any of the solutions provided work?

Answer (score 2):

I just did it like this:

This code comes to the file `latest_item.php`:

```
<?php if (isset($this->item->extra_fields)) : ?>
  <div class="catItemExtraFields">
    <ul>
    <?php if (is_string($this->item->extra_fields)) {
        $this->item->extra_fields = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields);
      }
      foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField) {
        if ($extraField->value != '') {
          echo "<li>".$extraField->name.": ".$extraField->value."</li>";
        }
      }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You could do some more checking for existing members and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display data from the extra fields inside the latest.php, then :

Inside the appropriate foreach loop that goes through your content items and prints out each k2 item go as this:

```
<?php $extra = json_decode($item->extra_fields); ?>
```

$extra will be an array with the extra fields and their values.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($extra); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: json_decode is lowercase http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @RiccardoZorn - oh yes - edited.